# Verberstsatz mit "doch"

Tags: sentence-structure

Folgendes Beispiel:

> Angela M. blieb den ganzen Tag im Bett, hatte sie sich doch bei einem Skiunfall verletzt.

- Welcher Satztyp ist der zweite Teilsatz?

Er ist ganz klar abhängig und funktioniert nicht allein. Also Nebensatz?

- Welche Funktion hat "doch" hier? Adverb oder Partikel?

Comment: Apropos, das war heute eine gute Gelegenheit, den Unterschied zwischen Passiv und Aktiv zu lernen: "Merkel ist gestürzt" vs. "Merkel wurde gestürzt". Wäre ich Zeitungsmacher, würde ich freilich mit "Merkel gestürzt!" aufmachen.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Der zweite Teilsatz ist ein kausaler Nebensatz, einige interessante Informationen findet man [in diesem pdf](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CCsQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fdigital-b.ub.uni-frankfurt.de%2Ffiles%2F12597%2FdochV1.pdf&ei=HLHKUu2qKrP74QTNjIAg&usg=AFQjCNFm8065YUXUn7Nv3ScRAi8ermqiIA&sig2=jUDEacyeVkJHWyvxvkNTIg&bvm=bv.58187178,d.bGE). Das relevante Zitat lautet:

> Sätze mit Verberststellung können im Deutschen   eine kausale Bedeutung haben, wobei sie jedoch eine Besonderheit aufweisen. In diesen Sätzen tritt immer unbetontes *doch* auf, dem der Status einer Modalpartikel zugeschrieben werden kann.

*doch* ist hier also eine Modalpartikel. Die Trennung zu Adverbien ist unscharf, weil sie oft als Untergruppe der Partikeln klassifiziert werden, und es teilweise vom Autor und den in Betracht gezogenen Aspekten abhängt, welche Wörter er wo einsortiert.

Quelle: Karin Pittner, Dialog in der Grammatik: Doch in Kausalsätzen mit Verberststellung, pdf oben verlinkt