# Die Verwendung von "sollte" am Satzbeginn

Tags: subjunctive, modal-verb

Neulich habe ich bemerkt, dass das Verb *sollen* (sollte) am Satzbeginn verwendet wird um Vermutungen auszudrücken. Dazu kann ich ein paar Beispiele nennen:

> ***Sollte* es Wissenschaftler eines Tages gelingen**, dann würde einem erfolgreichen Gewichtslust nichts mehr im Wege stehen.

> ***Sollte* diese Annahme richtig sein**, wie könnte dieser (ideologische) Wandel erklärt werden?

Ich frage mich, ob das Modalverb in diesen Fällen eine subjektive Bedeutung übernimmt. Wenn dem so ist, kann man *sollen* durch andere Modalverben ersetzen, um das Grad der Sicherheit des Sprechers abzustufen (z.B.: möchte, dürfte, könnte)?

Comment: Ich vermute "Gewichtsverlust", obwohl "Gewichtslust" eine sehr schöne Neuschöpfung  ist

Comment: Zur Voranstellung des Verbs in Nebensätzen hier auf Englisch: https://german.stackexchange.com/q/17355/35111

Comment: Was genau meinst du mit "*subjektive Bedeutung*"? Die Subjekte in in diesen (Neben?)Sätzen sind "*es*" und "*Annahme*". Und das Ganze funktioniert auch mit "*könnte*": "***Könnte** man Geld von Bäumen ernten, dann wären wir alle reich.*"

Comment: Danke für die Ermutigung @PaulFrost! Aus Versehen entstand dieser Neologismus!

Comment: @DavidVogt Das erklärt Vieles! Ich glaube, was mich erstmal verwirrt hat war eher die Wortstellung - wie in der ersten Antwort dargestellt wird - als der Modus. Vielen Dank.

Comment: @MartinRosenau Der Ausdruck "Subjektive Bedeutung"  bezieht sich auf eine aussergewöhnliche Verwendung der Modalverben, um einen bestimmter Grad von Wahrscheinlichkeit mitzuteilen. Mehr dazu: https://www.deutschplus.net/pages/Subjektive_Bedeutung_der_Modalverben. Dein Beispiel hat mir übrigens geholfen.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In diesem Fall liegt es m.E. weniger am Modalverb als am verwendeten Konjunktiv.

--> siehe Definition Konjunktiv = Möglichkeitsform

Und ja, insbesondere bei der Verwendung des **Konjunktiv II** bzw. Konj. Präteritum

> sollte, könnte, wollte, dürfte ... bzw. ginge, stünde ...

... drückt der Verfasser aus, dass er sich nicht sicher ist, ob die postulierte These je eintreten wird bzw. hält er sie für höchst oder auch gänzlich unwahrscheinlich.

Die implizite Haltung beim **Konjunktiv I** bzw. Konj. Infinitiv

> solle, könne, wolle, dürfe ... bzw. gehe, stehe ...

... ist, dass er der These neutral gegenüber steht bzw. für durchaus möglich hält - bezieht aber keine Position dazu. Sehr häufig verwenden Deutschsprachige jedoch durchgängig den Konjunktiv II, obwohl in vielen Fällen Konj. I angebracht wäre (z.B. weil im Plural der Konjunktiv I vom Präsens nicht zu unterscheiden ist und um Missverständnisse zu vermeiden), d.h. diese Abstufung im Hinblick auf den "Grad der Sicherheit" ist häufig nicht möglich.

Vor allem in Wien/Ostösterreich signalisiert die Verwendung des Konjunktivs II auch höfliches Verhalten, z.B. an der Käsetheke:

> Frage des Kunden: Könnte ich bitte 20 Deka vom Gouda haben?

*Ja, natürlich kann er - das steht außer Zweifel, solange noch Gouda vorrätig ist.*

---

ad "Grad der Sicherheit", mit der ein Verfasser sich ausdrückt

Ja und nein. Zum einen ist ja schon mittels Konjunktiv II klar, dass sich der Verfasser nicht sicher ist, zum anderen haben die Modalverben unterschiedliche Bedeutungen, die sehr gut und ausführlich z.B. auf duden.de beschrieben sind.

---

ps: ad "Sollte es Wissenschaftler eines Tages gelingen, dann würde einem erfolgreichen Gewichtslust nichts mehr im Wege stehen."
--> schöner formuliert wäre (hier schlägt mein Konjunktiv II etwas vor, ich sehe es aber nicht als zwingend an, diesen Vorschlag anzunehmen - also ausgenommen die Korrekturen rund um den/die Wissenschafter, den Gewichts**ver**lust sowie die Frage, was ihm/ihnen denn gelingen soll - diese sehe ich als notwendige Korrekturen an):

> Sollte es Wissenschafter**n** (*oder "dem Wissenschafter", wenn es nur einer ist*) eines Tages gelingen, *z.B. diese Pille zu entwickeln*, **stünde** einem erfolgreichen Gewichtslust nichts mehr im Wege.

oder - wenn das zu Entwickelnde bereits im vorangegangenen Text beschrieben ist:

> Sollte dies dem/den Wissenschafter/n eines Tages gelingen, stünde einem erfolgreichen Gewichts**ver**lust nichts mehr im Wege.

pps: Wissenschafter vs. Wissenschaft**l**er - nachdem es auch keinen Botschaftler oder Gewerkschaftler gibt, bevorzuge ich das "l" in diesem Wort wegzulassen, obwohl es der "Wissenschaft**l**er" inzwischen auch in den Duden geschafft hat (ursprünglich eine abwertende Variante, die sich zu meinem Bedauern durchgesetzt hat).

Comment: Vielen Dank für die ausführliche Antwort zur Verwendung der Modi und für die Hinweise.

Comment: Autsch für den "Wissenschafter". Der hat's noch nicht nach Deutschland geschafft und ist allerhöchstens in CH und AT gängig.

Comment: Mir ist schon bewusst, dass "Wissenschaftler" weitaus gebräuchlicher ist, auch wenn's ein bisserl schmerzt ... - die Anmerkung ist mehr als kleines Bonmot am Rande gedacht ...